# What is the physics behind a non-zero beam waist in Gaussian Beams?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation

I have been doing some deeper reading on optics out of my interest and one of the most important differences between ray and Gaussian optics is the existence of a non-zero beam waist when a laser beam is focused using a field lens. Most literatures that I have read go over this fact as if it's a common knowledge, but doesn't exactly over why this phenomenon occurs.

I understand that focusing to a single point would result in singularity which is physically impossible, but I was hoping if someone could explain what cause the beam waist behavior. Some literatures attribute it to diffraction, but I don't understand what causes this while a Gaussian beam is propagating in vacuum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's briefly imagine a monochromatic beam of light with no divergence. In the quantum picture, every photon in the beam has the same momentum, $\vec p = h\lambda \hat z$.  But the uncertainty principle demands that $\sigma_{p_x} \sigma_{x} \gtrsim \hbar$ in the transverse $x$- and $y$-directions, which means that a photon drawn from the beam must have either some random (and therefore nonzero) transverse momentum, or be highly delocalized in the transverse direction.  If your beam is small, its divergence is large.  But if a beam of light has large divergence, then somewhere later it will be wide — it'll diverge from its current size.

You can see the same sort of effect by considering only wave optics.  What's the easiest way to make a narrow beam of light?  You put a good plane wave behind some absorber that has a hole in it, like a pinhole.  But the smaller the hole is, the more important diffraction becomes.  If you make the width of the hole smaller than the wavelength of the light, then diffraction describes the *entire* transmitted beam.  You can't use a small pinhole to make an arbitrarily small beam of light.

Because of time-reversal symmetry, a diverging beam of light follows the same trajectory as a converging beam of light going the other direction.  If you can make a diverging beam from some aperture, then a sufficiently clever optical system can make a converging beam that would impinge on that same aperture — subject to all the constraints about diffraction at that location. Those constraints about diffraction are *also* subject to time-reversal symmetry, so there exists some minimum aperture that your beam of light could fit through.